# Basic authentication issue in JBoss Wildfly

Tags: authentication, jboss, wildfly, basic-authentication, jaas

I have created a new login process for my application. For that, I used "Basic" authentication and a new custom class for login validation. The authentication process is working fine. The issue I'm facing is, the custom login validation class is not invoked for all requests. Let me explain elaborately.

I login using a correct username & password. Now the custom class is invoked and it validates the username and password, then JBoss allows the connection. If I do logout and then login with same username and password, JBoss does not invoke my validation class, rather it allows the user to create a new connection right away, even though the user credentials have been modified or deleted in the database.

Note: I'm using JBoss Wildfly 8.2

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application I had used **cache-type="default"** in **security-domain** tag. I removed it, now JBoss uses no cache by default for my custom login module.

See more at https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276415